# How to Index a column of dates and Match to another column using dates with > & <= criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have a range of dates that are entered as events and would like to index the event dates and match to another column based on where the event date falls within a > and <= date criteria match.  I have tried some Min, Max options but always return with errors.  The formula format I have been using is below.   I with purpose show > & <= to identify the criteria.  The data is below also with the desired results showing in column F.

=INDEX(B2:B9, MATCH( > & <= , D2:D9 & E2:E9, 0))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enter the formula in cell `F2` and drag it throughout the range,

`=IF(COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,B:B,1),0))>0,"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,B:B,1),0))`

This formula uses `INDEX` `MATCH` to find the range where the date is present. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks.